# find orthonormal basis of span of 2 vectors in r4?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

Let $w = \mbox{span} \{(1,1,-2,0)^T,(1,0,2,1)^T\}$

Find an orthonormal basis for $w$ using dot product

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what I actually need to do.

Do I use gram-schmidt?
I only have 2 vectors, don't I need 4 to solve this?
if so, whats an easy way to choose 2 more vectors that I know are lineraly independant?

Comment: $w$ is 2-dimensional, so you do not need 4 vectors. Have you read this article? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

Comment: Yeah I know how to use gram schmidt.
w is 2 dimensional, but the vectors are 4 dimensional, does that matter?

Comment: so v1 = (1,1,-2,0)trans  and v2 = (1/2)*(3,1,2,2)
Is what I got, is that correct?

(next step would be to normalise v1 and v2?)

Comment: You are working in $\mathbb{R}^4$, but you are trying to find an orthonormal basis for $w$, which is a 2-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$. I referred you to that article not because I didn't think you knew how to follow the computational steps, but because I didn't think you understood what the Gram-Schmidt process actually *does*. And yes, that computation looks correct.

Comment: Thanks, so my final answer is (1/sqrt(6))*(1,1,-2,0)t
and v2 =  1/(3*sqrt(2))* (3,1,2,2)t

where t = transpose

is this the final correct answer?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @straykiwi to see if it is correct, check the dot-product between your final gram-schmidt'd vectors. Do you get zero? If so then they are indeed orthogonal and then you just need to check for length one.

Comment: And when you are sure you understand, you can post a solution, and then later you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Gram-Schmidt on $w$ which gives
$$v_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}(1,1,-2,0)$$
and
$$v_2 = \frac{1}{3\sqrt{2}}(3,1,2,2).$$